# Determining variance of UMVUE

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, unbiased-estimator

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be iid with pdf given by $f(x;\theta)=\frac{log\theta}{\theta^{x-1}}I(x>1)$. My task is to determine if the $\mu=E[X]=1+\frac{1}{log\theta}$ can be estimated efficiently, i.e. if the UMVUE for $\mu$ achieves the Cramer-Rao lower bound. Here's my work:

The pdf $f(x;\theta)$ is a member of the one-parameter exponential family, so $T=T(X)=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is complete-sufficient for $\theta$, i.e. for $\mu$. Furthermore, $g(T)=\frac{T}{n}$ is unbiased for $\mu$, so by Lehmann-Scheffe, $g(X)=\bar X$ is the UMVUE.

To see if $\bar X$ attains the Cramer-Rao lower-bound, we must calculate its variance, where $V[\bar X]=\frac{V[X]}{n}$. Here is where I'm stuck. To get $V[X]$, how should I calculate $E[X^2]$? Should I simply use the integration method? I believe it would require integration by parts twice, and I end up with very strange expression. Is there some other route I could take?

Comment: Integrating$$\int_1^\infty x^2\exp\{-\log(\theta)(x-1)\}\,\text{d}x$$should not be a major challenge...

Comment: Ah. I lost the negative sign in front of the log...Thanks